# Value of variable does not get passed on correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox on my webpage. Based on if the checkbox is checked the variable **abc_test** needs to be changed either to **"wfOutput"** or **"_blank"**.

On initial load the variable has the value of **"wfOutput"** but for some reason the formTarget does not react to the changes based on the variable value. If I change the variable manually everything works and the formTarget receives the correct value.

```
<input id='runwindow' type='checkbox'>      

 var abc_test = "wfOutput";
 $("#runwindow").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        abc_test = "_blank";
        return;
    }
        abc_test = "wfOutput";
});
```

The abc_test variable is used in the following code example.

```
var ap = $("<div>").autoprompt(
{                   
  wfdInfo:xmlInfo,
  formTarget:abc_test,
}).autoprompt("instance");
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know the solution as not familiar with `autoprompt` but the problem is that the settings object for autoprompt is only set once when the code first runs, therefore it will use the value of `abc_test` at that specific time only. You need someway to get the value dynamically as you need it, or update the values when you handle the check change event

Comment: Can you provide more information on the `autoprompt` method? If it's a plugin can you mention that and provide a link? If it's your own code then you should say so and maybe provide information on how those settings can be updated dynamically

Comment: @musefan yes it is a custom plugin. Unfortunaltly, I cannot add any code on here of the plugin. However, would there be a way to just recall the object everytime the checkbox get checked or unchecked? Thanks

Comment: It really depends on how the plugin has been coded. you could just try recalling the same code (but it may *add* to the prompts rather than update depending on the design), it's difficult to try and guess without seeing the code

Answer (score 4):

> but for some reason the formTarget does not react to the changes based on the variable value.

When you do

```
var ap = $("<div>").autoprompt(
{                   
  wfdInfo:xmlInfo,
  formTarget:abc_test,
}).autoprompt("instance");
```

the **value** of `abc_test` is read and assigned to the `formTarget` property of the object created by the initializer. There is no ongoing connection between the object property and the variable afterward; changing `abc_test` later has **no effect** on the object property.

You'll need to call `autoprompt` to update the `formTarget` option from your `change` handler. Most plugins offer some kind of "update" method.

Comment: Hmmm... to be honest, I am tempted to downvote this. Although you have obviously identified why it doesn't work, you don't really offer a solution to resolve the issue so it seems like an incomplete answer. Of course if you provided the code that does update the values it would be complete

Comment: @musefan: Your choice either way. I think it answers the question. The details of how you use that particular plugin aren't necessary, it's reasonable to leave that as an exercise for the person using it. (I did spend a few minutes trying to find the plugin in hopes I could help them with it *anyway*, but...)

Comment: Yeah, I guess if you can't find information on the plugin it would be unreasonable for you to provide code for it. On reflection you have probably taken it as far as you can